# In the time of the Mahabharata, how would royal priest worship a great rishi?

Tags: mahabharata, worship, rishi

[image]

The image, above, is an excerpt from Kisari Mohan Ganguli's translation of The Complete Mahabharata.

It describes the scene when Satyavati calls Vyasa (by thinking of him) to ask him to father children with the deceased Vichitravirya's wives for the progression of the Kuru lineage.

The passage mentions:

> The family priest of the Bharatas then worshipped the great Rishi
> duly, and the latter accepted the offerings of worship, uttered the
> usual mantras.

My question is: In those times, by what means would the royal priest worship a great Rishi who has come to the palace? Would they wash and touch his feet and offer him gifts? Or would they perform rituals and recite mantras? Is it mentioned anywhere, how such worship of a great rishi be done by a royal priest?